# Facebook friends count on profile page vs Facebook friends count on Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count

My facebook friends count on profile page is 135 but on Graph API is 132. I also tested on others account: some count exactly and some not. Is there any way to get the exactly count ?

Comment: Which graph api feed are you referring to? The friends feed https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends ?

Comment: Yes, it's graph.facebook.com/me/friends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching list of friends in Graph API or FQL - Appears to be missing some friends](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend)

Answer (score 2):

Could be that you need to page through the response to get the whole picture:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/